# Cache memory not keeping track of each file - Service worker

Tags: browser-cache, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I created a service worker where it loops through each of the files to add them to the cache storage but it doesn’t save all of the files every time. Also, each time I tried to create the app on a different device with the same code, it chooses which files to save even though the loop is static.

Does anyone have an idea of can be the issue?

```
var cacheName = 'erh-cache-v1';
var filesToCache = [
    '/',
    'index.html',
    '/dragon.js',
    '/app.js',
    '/menu.html',
    '/activeShooter.html',
    '/buildings.json',
    '/demonstrations.html',
    '/dragon.js',
    '/earthquakes.html',
    '/elevatorMalfunction.html',
    '/employees.json',
    '/fireEvacuation.html',
    '/flooding.html',
    '/bombThreat.html',
    '/gas.html',
    '/jquery-3.1.0.js',
    '/jquery.cookie.js',
    '/jquery.popmenu.min.js',
    '/keywords.json',
    '/localEmergencyContacts.html',
    '/manifest.json',
    '/medicalAssistance.html',
    '/menu.html',
    '/sw.js',
    '/powerFailure.html',
    '/script.js',
    '/search.png',
    '/settings.html',
    '/severeWeather.html',
    '/site.js',
    '/styles.css',
    '/suspiciousIndividuals.html',
    '/suspiciouspackage.html',
    '/theft.html',
    '/threateningBehaviour.html',
    '/unknownOrSuspiciousSubstances.html',
    '/violenceAndHarassment.html'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
            console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching app shell');

            return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: Could you post a code snippet?

Comment: Hi, I have added the code for the files that I want to get saved to the cache-memory. Did you need another part of the code?

Comment: How are you validating that it's not caching the files correctly?

Comment: @abraham, I don't see all the files in the cache storage on chrome (under applications, cache storage).

Comment: I would guess that weird is happening. `addAll` is supposed to be all or nothing. If any single resource fails nothing should get cached. `'/sw.js'` is one of the files so maybe an old version of the service worker that has a different list of files is being used.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your explanation. I tried it on a new device and I still have the same issue.